# How do I find MAX value of one column and place it into specific row of another column

Tags: mysql

HERE IS MY TABLE EXAMPLE:

```
Time     |  Predicted |   Actual |   High
---------+------------+----------+---------
01:00:00 |  100       |    100   |    NULL
02:00:00 |  200       |    50    |    NULL
01:00:00 |  150       |    100   |    NULL
02:00:00 |  180       |    80    |    NULL
```

I want to find highest value in Predicted and place it in the 'High' column (IN A SPECIFIC ROW)

=========
This is what I have so far  - two independent statements, however I want to combine into one action.

```
UPDATE table SET High="200" WHERE Time='01:00:00';

INSERT INTO table (High) SELECT MAX(Predicted) AS Predicted FROM table;;
```

When I use the above **INSERT** Statement I get:

```
Time     |  Predicted |    Actual |   High
---------+------------+-----------+---------
01:00:00 |  100       |    100    |   NULL
02:00:00 |  200       |    50     |   NULL
01:00:00 |  150       |    100    |   NULL
02:00:00 |  180       |    80     |   NULL
00:00:00 |  NULL      |    NULL   |   200
```

=======================================

**I want to somehow combine the above two statements and the following result**

```
Time     |  Predicted  |   Actual |   High
---------+-------------+----------+--------
01:00:00 |  100        |   100    |   200
02:00:00 |  200        |   50     |   NULL
01:00:00 |  150        |   100    |   NULL
02:00:00 |  180        |   80     |   NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve expected result by using following query. But not sure if its possible to use single query.

```
SET @predicted=(SELECT MAX(Predicted) FROM table);
UPDATE table SET High=@predicted WHERE Time='01:00:00';
```

Comment: Thanks guys for the answer - this is great you've saved my a tone of agro

Comment: Thanks Ulias for cleaning up my question it is more legible - I will keep that in mind for future questions.

Comment: Its better if you accept any answer if you get solution

Answer (score 2):

Create function **get_max_predicted**

```
CREATE FUNCTION `get_max_predicted`()
    RETURNS int(11)
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    READS SQL DATA
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
GET_MAX_PREDICTED: BEGIN

    DECLARE `_maxPredicted` INT;    

    SELECT MAX(predicted) INTO _maxPredicted
    FROM  `table`;
    IF _maxPredicted IS NULL THEN 
        SET _maxPredicted = 0;
    END IF; 

    RETURN _maxPredicted;   
END;
```

and use this on update

```
UPDATE table SET High=get_max_predicted() WHERE Time='01:00:00';
```